# I am stuck on page 3 of Meteor Tutorial 2015-04-16

Tags: meteor

Currently I am on the [3step of the meteor tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/try/3)

The first failure was this command:

```
meteor mongo
```

According to google that command now fails due to a known bug.

So, I work around it with this command:

```
mongo --port 3001
```

Next I tried this command from the mongo prompt:

```
dan@u77:~/mets/simple-todos $ 
dan@u77:~/mets/simple-todos $ 
dan@u77:~/mets/simple-todos $ mongo --port 3001
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:3001/test
meteor:PRIMARY> 
meteor:PRIMARY> db.tasks.insert({ text: "Hello world!", createdAt: new Date() });
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
meteor:PRIMARY> 
meteor:PRIMARY>
```

According to the tutorial, I should now see a task in the template.

But, I see nothing.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
// simple-todos.js

Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: function () {
      return Tasks.find({});
    }
  });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<head>
  <title>Todo List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
    </header>

    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="task">
  <li>{{text}}</li>
</template>
```

Comment: if you run on the console of the browser `Tasks.findOne` or `Tasks.find().fetch()` what you get? the task is really inserted on the collection?

Comment: Also try in the mongo console: `db.tasks.findOne()`

Comment: @user3676943 Note that in order for `meteor mongo` to work, `meteor` must still be running in another terminal.

Comment: I think the problem with your call to `mongo --port 3001` is that it connects to the `test` database rather than the `meteor` database. But there is no reason why `meteor mongo` shouldn't work, please be more specific about how it fails!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue and the reason it wasn't working was because I'd forgotten to include tasks.js in **servers/main.js**:

```
  import '../imports/api/tasks.js';
```

The tutorial does suggest this.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into that issue and that was because I had removed autopublish. 
Make sure you have the autopublish package by running:

```
    meteor add autopublish
```